# В чем может быть задержка анимации ?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, анимация

Есть пример http://toyfight.co/ , на самом первом экране две игрушки плавно двигаются из стороны в сторону в зависимости от курсора.

На моем реальном примере есть следующие проблемы, в хроме есть рывки, хотя задержки нет никакой, а в мазилле просто идёт задержка и далее уже плавно смещается, реальный пример тяжело перенести на jsfiddle, поэтому подготовил подобное, правда в подготовленном примере Хром вроде хорошо работает, а вот в мазиле проблема осталась и не понятно откуда появляется задержка.

Может нужно изменять значения left, top, а не через translate ?

```js
 $('.wrap').mousemove(function(e) {
  var mpHeight = $('.wrap').height();
  var mpWidth = $('.wrap').width();
  var cX = e.clientX;
  var cY = e.clientY;
 
   if (cX < mpWidth/2) {
    cX = e.clientX - mpWidth/2;
   } else {
    cX = e.clientX - mpWidth/2;
   }
   if (cY < mpHeight/2) {
    cY = e.clientY - mpHeight/2;
   } else {
    cY = e.clientY - mpHeight/2;
   }
  
   $('.animate-object').css({
    "transform" : "translateX(" + -cX/20  + "px) translateY(" + -cY/20 + "px)"
   });
 });
```

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 900px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.animate-object {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform .5s linear
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate doloribus nisi sunt alias omnis, quidem qui illum obcaecati vitae accusamus nam eligendi voluptas impedit quasi saepe unde fugiat architecto perspiciatis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate doloribus nisi sunt alias omnis, quidem qui illum obcaecati vitae accusamus nam eligendi voluptas impedit quasi saepe unde fugiat architecto perspiciatis.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate doloribus nisi sunt alias omnis, quidem qui illum obcaecati vitae accusamus nam eligendi voluptas impedit quasi saepe unde fugiat architecto perspiciatis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate doloribus nisi sunt alias omnis, quidem qui illum obcaecati vitae accusamus nam eligendi voluptas impedit quasi saepe unde fugiat architecto perspiciatis.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate doloribus nisi sunt alias omnis, quidem qui illum obcaecati vitae accusamus nam eligendi voluptas impedit quasi saepe unde fugiat architecto perspiciatis.</p>
  
  <span class="animate-object"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Да в FF не все гладко...